# Disable Chromes Ctrl+P handling of printing

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, printing, flag

How can I disable Google Chrome's <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> handling of printing (i.e. return the keyboard shortcut to Windows and how it handles printing)?

Windows 7 64-bit
Chrome `v13.0.782.112`

Edit, Now that I know how, this generates a more interesting question, can you add more than one disable flag to the shortcut target box?, and how?

Update, as of version 14.0.835.163, you can disable print preview in About:Flags

.

Comment: Not sure if it is better for the site to post the edit as answer?

Comment: I think it is better if you've found your own answer to add it as an answer. Means it doesn't look unanswered in the activity feed and when looking through the tags... not that I'm an expert though! (except of course if the actual question has changed I guess.)

Comment: @moab: From the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq#questions), `"It’s also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question"`.

Comment: I know that, just wanted to give it to the person that answered the second question, which I didn't know. no rep points when I answer it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To temporarily disable Chrome's new Print Preview feature and use the OS's instead, as Moab already noted, add the flag/command-line-switch `--disable-print-preview` to your shortcut to Chrome. For example:

```
"C:\Users[user name]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-print-preview
```

or

```
C:\Users[user name]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --disable-print-preview
```

An image, for reference:

[image]

(Source: Moab's edit and indirectly [this](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=744242529a3bd65f&hl=en) thread.)

---

To have multiple flags (disable multiple features, for instance), add them one after the other, for example:

```
C:\Users[user name]\...\chrome.exe --disable-print-preview --disable-javascript
```

disables print previewing and javascript. Useful Chrome flags can be found [here](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).

Comment: Oh, double dash, thanks. it is not in my flags, looked. If you will add the other answer I found to your post, I will accept both, thanks.

Comment: @Moab Wait what? I just got thoroughly confused by your comment.

Comment: I wound up with 2 questions, I answered one in the original post, not good, should be posted as an answer, then you answered my other question, I want to combine them into one answer and mark your post as the accepted answer, this will help the site when others are searching. I can only accept one answer. My bad.